# How to remove files dynamically from upload form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, file-upload, input

I want to create multiupload file component with possibility of removing added files dynamically with javascript (when user click on close button on file preview).

I tried to use `<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>`
But as I found later there is no possibility of changing file input value dynamically :(

So what should I do for solving this problem? How to make possibility of removing files from form after it has been added by user?

Comment: Once you are using jquery, why not take some plugin? There are tons of plugins with multiple files upload

Comment: And... what have you tried? Or you want SO to make your work for you?

Comment: I don't know how to remove files from input, so I tried nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: take a look at [this](http://www.onlinesolutionsdevelopment.com/blog/web-development/php/create-multiple-file-uploader-using-php-html-and-jquery/) article. Here is how you can make multiple file upload (very simple, file is selected one by one)

Second: I do not think you can edit list of files in `<input type="file" multiple />` with JS. According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement) `.files` property is readonly (so you can get a list of files, but noting more). But at the same time, take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications). There you can find how to upload files with ajax. Once you can do that, you can show a list of selected files and allow user to remove some of them. And upload only files that are still in a list of selected files.